# How to count number of consecutive events matching status of last event?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

In MS-SQL Server 2008, I have a table of events in the following format:

```
Controller   |  ExecutionTime        |  Result
1            |  2012-09-24 09:00:00  | 0
1            |  2012-09-24 09:01:00  | 0
2            |  2012-09-24 09:02:00  | 1
```

I need to analyze this table to produce a result that:

- Identifies each controller whose latest event was an error (result=1)
- Identifies how many consecutive failures that controller has had (# events since the most recent successful event)

I've made some progress toward this task, I can identify the controllers whose most recent event was a failure - see **[this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/15592)**.  But I could use some help finding an approach to counting the # of consecutive failures that has led to this state.

Thanks!
John

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one solution. Not very efficient I'm afraid:

```
SELECT 
    t.Controller,
    MIN(t.ExecutionTime) AS FirstFaultInSeries,
    MAX(t.ExecutionTime) AS LatestFault,
    COUNT(*) AS CntFaults
FROM
  ( SELECT 
        Controller, 
        COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN Result = 0 THEN ExecutionTime END)
                ,'19000101')
          AS LatestGood
    FROM t    
    GROUP BY Controller
  ) g
  JOIN t
    ON t.Controller = g.Controller
   AND t.ExecutionTime > g.LatestGood
GROUP BY
    t.Controller ;
```

Tested: [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ca642/7)

And another:

```
WITH cte AS
  ( SELECT 
        Controller, ExecutionTime, Result,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Controller
                           ORDER BY ExecutionTime DESC
                          )
          AS Rn,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Controller, Result
                           ORDER BY ExecutionTime DESC
                          )
          AS RnResult
    FROM t
  ) 
SELECT 
    Controller,
    MIN(ExecutionTime) AS FirstFaultInSeries,
    MAX(ExecutionTime) AS LatestFault,
    COUNT(*) AS CntFaults
FROM
    cte 
WHERE
    Result = 1
  AND
    Rn = RnResult
GROUP BY
    Controller ;
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the typical "islands and gaps" problem. Itzik Ben Gan describes this problem and its solution in a chapter of "MVP deep dives".

It's a great book and Itzik's chapter alone would be a great reason to buy it. A sample of that chapter can be found here: http://www.manning.com/nielsen/SampleChapter5.pdf

A description of the algorithm can be found here [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20151009215313/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/samlester/archive/2012/09/04/tsql-solve-it-your-way-gaps-and-islands-with-a-twist.aspx) with three different implementations.

Basically, it's all about using ranking functions to assign a number to each partition of consecutive rows with the same value in one or more columns.

I'm sorry I can't post a solution based on your fiddle, but this should put you in the right direction and it's the best I can do from my mobile.

Comment: I appreciate that you gave me insight to the broader context of this problem and the overall patterns that apply!  I wasn't aware of the name - I'll start researching now.